# Do transactions prevent other updates for a while, or just hide them?

Tags: mysql, transactions

When doing a transaction in a mysql db, they are talking about the ongoing transaction not being able to see any updates made by external sources until it commits. So does this mean that changes CAN be made but the transaction just will not be able to see them, or is it actually impossible to update the db while the transaction is going on.

Because I need it to be impossible for other queries to change anything about certain tables while the transaction is going. Right now I write lock all those tables, start a transaction for the atomicity, commit, and than unlock. Is this the way to do this?

From my testing it seems that setting the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE accomplishes the same as manual table locking and unlocking? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend on the transaction isolation level you have set on your database. You can read more about the levels [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html). For example, for READ UNCOMMITTED, you can actually read rows that are uncommitted by another transaction. This is usually not what you want to happen.

Locking an entire table is a really extreme choice though, and should probably not be done unless there's no other choice. My recommendation would be to consider the rows you need to lock, and then you can lock those specific rows using a select for update statement.

For example, suppose you have a resources table and a schedules table that contains bookings for those resources. When booking a resource, you have to check the schedules table for a given resource to make sure it's available for the desired time. However, you have to do this is a concurrent way, that is, you want to ensure that between the time you check the schedules table for availability for the resource, and the time you actually insert the row into the schedules table, you want to ensure that some other transaction doesn't book the resource for the same time (or an overlapping time).

You can accomplish this by using a select for update command:

```
select * from resources where resource_name=’a’ for update;
```

Assuming you're doing this in a stored procedure, if some other code fires the stored procedure for the same resource, it will block on that statement. This will ensure that resources don't get double booked.

We could also accomplish this by locking the entire resources table. However, there's no need to do that since we're only interested in booking a single resource. So it's good enough to just lock the resource row we care about.

Note that for MySQL, you need to index the columns you use in the for update or it will lock the entire table.

The point to all this is to always consider maximum concurrency. In other words, don't lock more than you need to. Otherwise, you make the application much less scalable and you inhibit concurrency.

Comment: Oke thanks for the reply. But what do you mean by 'assuming you're doing this in a stored procedure?' If I execute this as the first line in a multiple-query statement, it would still keep the rows locked for the further duration of that statement right? even if its not in a procedure

Comment: Yes, it will keep the row(s) locked for the duration of the transaction. I assume here you are using transactions in your code.